# Displaying a MessageBox prevents IsChecked from firing

Tags: c#, binding, checkbox

I have a few `TextBoxes` that are bound to a single `CheckBox`.

This is the logic associated with it:

- If the `Checkbox` is checked, it will overwrite any existing text in the associated `TextBoxes` and make it '0'**++**
- If all of the `TextBoxes` have a score of '0,' the `CheckBox` should
  become disabled and checked.
- If any of the `TextBoxes` then change from '0,' it will become
  enabled and unchecked.

**++** **Note:**  The caveat to this is if the `TextBox` has a value of 'C.'

Okay, so the issue I have is implementing the caveat above when one of the associated `TextBoxes` has a value of 'C.'  What I would like to have happen is loop through the `TextBoxes` and check to see if any are scored 'C.'  If one is found, display a warning message to the user confirming if they want to proceed.  If Yes is selected, all associated scores will be overwritten to '0.' If No is selected then the `Checked` event should be cancelled.

To accomplish this, I added Event Listeners for the `CheckBox.PreviewMouseDown` and `CheckBox.Checked` events.  Here is the code for my `CheckBox.PreviewMouseDown` event listener:

```
private void NormalCheckBoxControl_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox normalCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    bool showCorrespondingScoreWarningMsg = false;

    //Get a Row to loop through the AssociatedAdqScore controls for each
    ScoreControl tempScoreControl = new ScoreControl();

    foreach (ScoreControl score in this.ScoreControlList)
    {
        if (score.ScoreTextBox.Text == "C")
        {
            showCorrespondingScoreWarningMsg = true;
        }
    }

    if (showCorrespondingScoreWarningMsg)
    {
        MessageBoxResult msgResult = InformationBox.Show("WARNING: Proceeding will remove corresponding 'C' scores.  Continue?", "Continue?", ButtonStyle.YesNo, IconStyle.Question);

        if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This works if the user selects 'No,' however the issue I'm having is that when choosing 'Yes,' the `CheckBox.Checked` event still does not get fired.  I have tried to manually set `CheckBox.IsChecked = true;` if `if (msgResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)`, but this breaks the bindings so that is not a viable solution.

Is there any way I can resolve this issue and proceed with the `NormalCheckBoxControl_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` event if the user selects 'Yes?'

Comment: Why not bind the `IsChecked` property of your `CheckBox` to a property? That way, when you bind `CheckBox.IsChecked` to the property, then you just change the property when a `TextBox` criteria matches what you want and it'll automatically check/uncheck your `CheckBox` for you when you change the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a "Checked" event, though there is a `CheckedChanged` event and also a `CheckStateChanged` event. I am used to .NET 2.0, so this may be a 3.0+ thing. Either way, I think I have manually called the event handler in instances like this without any problem.

You can manually call the event handler with null params (or known object & new event args):

```
NormalCheckBoxControl_Checked(null, null);
```

or

```
NormalCheckBoxControl_Checked(new object, new EventArgs());
```

This should manually kick off your routine, and unless you need them, then there's really no problem with providing dummy params. No need to raise an event and wait for it to bubble, just call the routine.

Of course, if there are other routines which rely on the event bubbling or if you have multiple handlers for the same event, then it might cause you a problem. Be aware of that, just in case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if manually kicking off the event will work for me.  FYI - my application is using .NET Framework 4.0, so it's possible that `CheckBox.Checked` wasn't added in until 3.0+

Comment: I just checked on MSDN, looks like 3.0 changed the event names. No biggie, it should still work. I'm working up a WinForms 2.0 example to see if it does.

Comment: With some minor updates to the logic within the event listeners, calling `NormalCheckBoxControl_Checked(null, null)` explicitly worked; thanks!  I wasn't aware that it was possible to call event listeners manually (let alone being able to call them with `null` parameters!) without actually raising an event to fire it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Be aware that there may be a race condition going on, not sure how your whole code works. Just make sure that the checkbox is actually checked (or unchecked) before manually calling the Event handler.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep that in mind but there shouldn't be a race condition - the only time `NormalCheckBox_PreviewMouseDown()` will be called is when the user clicks it while it is unchecked (Un-checking is handled via bindings), so if the `PreviewMouseDown` event isn't handled, `NormalCheckBox_Checked()` should always be called.